Removing a combination from stacked parametrization in pytest
For a lot of tests we use a stacked parametrizing for testing our functions like this:
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", x.values()) #possible values 1,2,3,4
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", y.values()) #possible values True, False
def test_get_somehting(x):
    get_something(x, y)

Now I want to run all combinations except for the combination x=3 and y=False Only I have not found an intuitive way to do that. Almost all test run with these parameters so I'd rather not specify them separately every test. Any idead how to go about this? thanks!

You can create a function to handle the tests parameters
def parametrize():
    for i in x.values():
        for b in y.values():
            if i != 3 or b is True:
                yield i, b


@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", parametrize())
def test_get_somehting(x, y):
    get_something(x, y)

Output
collected 7 items

test_get_somehting[1-True] PASSED                      [ 14%]
test_get_somehting[1-False] PASSED                     [ 28%]
test_get_somehting[2-True] PASSED                      [ 42%]
test_get_somehting[2-False] PASSED                     [ 57%]
test_get_somehting[3-True] PASSED                      [ 71%]
test_get_somehting[4-True] PASSED                      [ 85%]
test_get_somehting[4-False] PASSED                     [100%]

